# Batch file is not running through Windows 7 Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, batch-processing

I have a batch file that executes a php script which fetches files(pdfs) from the backend and saves locally. I have tried executing the batch file through command prompt and it works perfectly.

But when I setup a Windows Task Scheduler to run this batch, it is not working. The command prompt window pop ups and displays alot of unreadable characters and hangs there.

I have also chosen the option for the bat to run with highest privileges but no difference.

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: maybe that if you provide more infos you will have more responses ... what is in your batch ? how do you call it in the scheduler? what is the output etc.

Comment: When you call your batch file from the task scheduler, do you call it as `cmd /c "path\to\batch.bat"` or just as `"path\to\batch.bat"`?  Does calling it the other way make any difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake. Managed to solve it. The path to php was not set properly.

Now it is fine.